# Use Azure Runbook to upload files from local machine or network drive to Azure file share or blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

So I am trying to create a PowerShell runbook to automate the upload of files from local machine and network drives to an Azure storage account. I have tried doing this with Set-AzureStorageFileContent however get the error that the directory does not exist.

Any help would be greatly received.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runbooks run on the azure cloud platform, and it does not know(cannot communicate with) your local storage.

I suggest you can use [Hybrid Runbook Worker feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) of Azure Automation to run runbooks directly on your computer, which can access those local resources.